# How are Java byte variables stored with 8 bits

Tags: java, variables, binary, byte

I can't find an explanation but I have an idea.
Byte type can store numbers from -128 to 127.
MSB states for positive (1) or negative (0).
Negative numbers are inverted positive binary numbers. For example if `101` is `5`, `010` is `-5` (if MSB is `1`).

But why we can store -128 in Byte variable?

My guess is:
if `0000 0000` is zero (plus) we don't need minus zero anymore so -128 can be stored as `1111 1111` (minus inverted binary zero).

Can anybody confirm or explain how this is working?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: Almost. -128 is 10000000.

Comment: okay so -1 is stored with minus zero and so on. I was close to :)

Comment: I took closer look at  en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement and now I know that I was completly wrong. Negative byte values are stored as 128-0 is -128, 128-1 is -127, 128-2 is -126 and so on.